# How to flag question as belonging on another site?

Tags: bug, flagging

If I flag a question as needing improvement, I'm presented with this choice:

[image: Why isn't this question suited for Skeptics.SE?]

---

If I select the last one (belongs on another site), I get Hobson's choice:

[image: What site does this question belong on?]

---

Only one site is offered, the wrong one where the question already is.

The only place to navigate to from here is "back".

Something isn't working as it should.

Answer (score 3):

What you see there are so-called 'migration paths'; by default, only the meta site is listed there, but Community Managers can add other sites; [up to four others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96345/295232). Whether it's worthwhile doing so depends on how often questions are migrated; 10k users can check this via the [10k tools](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats).

If you want to migrate a question to an arbitrary site in the network, you'll have to raise a custom flag, as indicated in the [FAQ about migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/295232).

Comment: Ah, I missed the "meta" in the site name.  But either way, the path seemed obvious, and the destination very confusing.

Comment: Yeah, a custom mod flag is the way to go here. Regular users have limited options, but moderators can migrate questions to any site on the network they choose, even to other sites' Metas.

Comment: I'll add that I tend to be loathe to do unnecessary migrations. If a question hasn't any answers, the OP can simply cut-and-paste the text into another site, and delete the local question; it doesn't need a mod and the elaborate rules that dictate how a migration works.